# Email account expired - how can I get Outlook 2010 to stop asking for a password?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a fairly simple question: I had mapped a work account to Outlook that I no longer have. However, every time I start up Outlook, it asks me for the password to that account. I just want the old emails to sit there, and not refresh or try to sync with the mail server. How can I make this happen?

### Update 1:

@CharlieRB's suggestion leads to this:
[image]

I will of course backup my account now, but wanted to understand what exactly "cached content" means?

### Update 2:

So it turns out that my Exchange Server account has an .ost file that [cannot be moved easily](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2752583). Any advice on how to either:

- stop Outlook 2013 from asking for a password every time I open up Outlook; or,
- how to move the offline files associated with the account so that the files do not get deleted when I remove the account,

would be appreciated.

Comment: In any case i would back up the ost file before trying to delete the profile / account.

Comment: Is this old account an exchange account? Or is it IMAP/ POP3?

Comment: Cache used by exchange accounts is kinda a local copy of you exchange e-mail account. When you are offline you can access the cached(offline) e-mails and setting. If you would remove all cache on an exchange account it would mean to remove all local data and you only would have access to you mailbox when you are connected to the mail server via lan or wan.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic It is an exchange account, and in my case, [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2752583) applies.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic Yeah, so it turns out that removing the account is not an option without going through some pretty horrific maneuvering mentioned in the page linked in the comment above.

Comment: In that case, Ivan's answer to create an archive may be the best solution. Had this been a POP3 account, it would've been so much easier.

Comment: So if you remove the cache i think you data will be lost. You could just try it but first of all you should close outlook and then make a copy of the file. I still think the most simple way is just to copy the mails into a pst file.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic Then the question is: 1. how do I create a PST backup, and 2. how do I access my files in the future? Sorry, I am not a regular Outlook user -- help appreciated.

Comment: Create PST : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Outlook-Data-File-pst-to-save-your-information-17a13ca2-df52-48e8-b933-4c84c2aabe7c

Comment: After creating the pst you should see a new folder in outlook. You can just move any folder or mail with the mouse to move it into the archive or rightclick mails/folders when marked and then use "move to" and select the archive. Be aware that pst file have some limits (50GB) but i usually would not use archives bigger than 10GB because they are getting slow fast when you search them. When reaching the limit you could just create a new archive.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic I created the PST file using the instructions given in the link, and it showed up in Outlook as well, but there are no emails (or anything else) in that folder.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic My guess is that even creation of the PST file requires credentials and authentication on the Exchange Server.

Comment: No you dont have to enter credentials for the pst, this is optional. Of cause there are no mail in the PST because it is a new file. Now after you created the file you need to move the old mails to this file. Try disconnection from the internet before opening outlook and then you should not get the passwort question, move all mail to the pst and then remove the account. Then you connect to you network again.

Comment: @IvanViktorovic You are a star. :D Many thanks for your help. PS. I have marked your answer as accepted, but you might want to add more detail to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a new archive pst and move all mails there and then remove the old e-mail account.

Update 1:

Cache used by exchange accounts is kinda a local copy of you exchange e-mail account. When you are offline you can access the cached(offline) e-mails and setting. If you would remove all cache on an exchange account it would mean to remove all local data and you only would have access to you mailbox when you are connected to the mail server via lan or wan.

Update 2:

This is how you could create a new PST file (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Outlook-Data-File-pst-to-save-your-information-17a13ca2-df52-48e8-b933-4c84c2aabe7c)

Now after you created the file you need to move the old mails to this file. Try disconnection from the internet before opening outlook and then you should not get the passwort question, move all mail to the pst and then remove the account. Then you connect to you network again.

To move you mails into the PST file you could use autoarchive mechanics (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AutoArchive-settings-explained-444bd6aa-06d0-4d8f-9d84-903163439114) or simply move any folder or mail with the mouse to move it into the archive or rightclick mails/folders when marked and then use "move to" and select the archive. Be aware that pst file have some limits (50GB) but i usually would not use archives bigger than 10GB because they are getting slow fast when you search them. When reaching the limit you could just create a new archive.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `File > Account Settings > Email tab` and remove the account in question. These are the connection settings which Outlook is trying to make contact with and asks for the password.

[image]

The data will stay in the inbox or folder you currently have it in, but Outlook will stop trying to connect to that account.

[Source (at the bottom of the page)](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Add-or-remove-an-email-account-5a74e3be-7e11-4d9b-99f7-08ec25e9d072?ui=en-US#__toc301268941)

Comment: I have updated the question per your suggestion -- can you clarify what exactly "cached content" means?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just wanted to keep the account around to look at old emails occasionally, but didn't want to export/import them anywhere.  I found this procedure online and it got rid of the annoying attempts to Send/Receive without deleting the account:

When you want to stop using an email account with Microsoft Outlook, you can disable the account so that you no longer receive emails. All of your saved messages will remain intact, and you can change your mind at any time. However, until you completely delete the account, you will still be able to send messages from the account.

Launch Outlook and click the "Send/Receive" tab.

Click "Send/Receive Groups" on the ribbon, and then select "Define
   Send/Receive Groups."

Select the "All Accounts" send/receive group in the new window, and
   then click the "Edit" button.

Select the account you want to disable, and then clear the check box
   next to "Include the Selected Account in This Group." Click "OK" to
   save the change.

Repeat the previous steps for any other send/receive groups displayed
   in the list. Click "Close" once you have removed the account from all
   the groups. Outlook will no longer receive mail from the account;
   however, you can still send messages from the account at this point.