# Use offline mailbox in Outlook 2016 without asking for credentials on startup

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm using Outlook 2016 (on Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC), and one mailbox (Exchange) was recently deactivated. Since I like the option of **searching through my old emails in Outlook** itself, I did not want to remove it from Outlook but instead use it in a **Offline-only** setting.

For some reason, however, I can't find an option to **deactivate the prompt** asking for credentials when I start Outlook. I can just click away this window and everything works fine (no synchronization performed, but I can check my old emails), but it reappears on the next restart.

Is there a better way how I can store my old mailbox in a *easily accessible* way?

**PS:**
The "Use cached exchange mode" option is already activated.
And in the settings the "always prompt for logon credentials" is not activated (but greyed out):

[image: Setting for user prompt deactivated]

**PPS:**
I found this question on superuser: [Email account expired - how can I get Outlook 2010 to stop asking for a password?](https://superuser.com/questions/869634/email-account-expired-how-can-i-get-outlook-2010-to-stop-asking-for-a-password?rq=1)
The accepted answer suggests to create a PST file and then move the mails to this PST folder. However, this does not seem to work in my case since copying/moving is somehow prohibited by the "Exchange Server Administrator". [image: Error message]

Comment: I think you'll need to follow the linked question.

Comment: I actually tried but without success, because copying is somehow prohibited (added it to the original question in PPS).

Comment: I have done a lot of research on this, but I haven't found any effective methods. In regard of Outlook client, I'm afraid your needs can't be realized.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the .OST file that relates to your account, then use an OST to PST converter that will convert the mailbox to a PST. The OST file is located at `\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`

Outlook must be fully quit, which most of the time it doesn't. If you can get an administrative cmd window then use `taskkill /im outlook* /f` to fully quit outlook before you copy the OST file to another location to start the convertion.

There are many OST to PST converters, None of which are free. You will need to pay for the application.

Comment: And by this I should be able to circumvent the issue with the missing permissions to copy it? I would like to avoid buying it and then ending up at the same point again...

Comment: Yes, as the PST file will be newly created from your OST file and therefore won't have any permissions.

Comment: Also, check you can find and copy your OST to another destination before anything else.